# Internal details for @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) and @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML}) argument types?

Tags: java, java-8

I see @produces annotation allows me to pass single string and list of string. so am just wondering how this done in java and if i need to implement this with a method which allow the below behavior, how can i do that ? or is this annotation specific so we cannot implement in class ?

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

 @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
```

Comment: In method level, give `String...` a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe what you want in method level:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("1");
    test("1", "2");
  }

  private static void test(String... args) {
    // do something
  }
```

As for the `{}` part in annotation, it meas the field is defined as an array, and the absence of `{}` when only one value is for convinience.

Comment: annotation has method with a type as String[]
String[] value() default "*/*";

Comment: it seems like they are using String[] and using default as String for single value

Comment: Yes, in method level,a similar situation is to pass `new String[]{"1", "2"}` to a method that take a `String[]` as parameter. Cannot be the same as annotation. @Pradeep